# Why do I always get null from fethcing data type BLOB in postgesql

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, odoo

I would like to get image from postgresql in odoo with rest-api python3, but I can't get it because

 response data always show null.

[image]


This is My model:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class HrAttendanceBreak(models.Model):
    _name = "hr.attendance.break"
    _rec_name = 'rec_name'


    rec_name = fields.Char(string="Record Name", compute='_get_rec_name', store=True)
    attendance_id = fields.Many2one('hr.attendance',ondelete='cascade', store=True,copy=False,string='Attendance Reference')
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee")

    jam_istirahat = fields.Datetime(string="Jam Istirahat")
    x_long_break = fields.Char(string="X, Longitude Break")
    y_lat_break= fields.Char(string="Y, Latitude Break")
    concat_break = fields.Char(string="Latlong Break")
    break_photo = fields.Binary(string='Break Photo', attachment=False)

    jam_lanjutKerja = fields.Datetime(string="Lanjut Kerja")
    x_long_resume = fields.Char(string="X, Longitude Resume")
    y_lat_resume= fields.Char(string="Y, Latitude Resume")
    concat_resume = fields.Char(string="Latlong Resume")
    resume_photo = fields.Binary(string='Resume Photo', attachment=False)
```

Im using `fields.Binary()` for store `break_photo` and `resume_photo` into database.

[image]

This is how I fetching data:

```
@http.route('/api/hr.attendance.break', type='http', auth="none", methods=['GET'], csrf=False)
    def hr_attendance_breake_list(self, **payload):
        model = 'hr.attendance.break'
        ioc_name = model
        model = request.env[self._model].sudo().search(
            [('model', '=', model)], limit=1)

        custFields = [
            'id', 'employee_id', 'jam_istirahat', 'jam_lanjutKerja', 
            'x_long_break', 'y_lat_break', 'break_photo', 
            'x_long_resume', 'y_lat_resume', 'resume_photo'
            ]
        
        if model:
            domain, fields, offset, limit, order = extract_arguments(payload)
            fields = custFields
            data = request.env[model.model].sudo().search_read(
                domain=domain, fields=fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
            if data:
                return valid_response(data)
            else:
                return valid_response(data)
        return invalid_response('invalid object model', 'The model %s is not availablee in the registry.' % ioc_name)
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Show us how you are fetching the data.

Comment: I have already update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Odoo there is an existing controller to retrieve images called `content_image` with the following routes definition

```py
[
    '/web/image',
    '/web/image/<string:xmlid>',
    '/web/image/<string:xmlid>/<string:filename>',
    '/web/image/<string:xmlid>/<int:width>x<int:height>',
    '/web/image/<string:xmlid>/<int:width>x<int:height>/<string:filename>',
    '/web/image/<string:model>/<int:id>/<string:field>',
    '/web/image/<string:model>/<int:id>/<string:field>/<string:filename>',
    '/web/image/<string:model>/<int:id>/<string:field>/<int:width>x<int:height>',
    '/web/image/<string:model>/<int:id>/<string:field>/<int:width>x<int:height>/<string:filename>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>/<string:filename>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>/<int:width>x<int:height>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>/<int:width>x<int:height>/<string:filename>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>-<string:unique>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>-<string:unique>/<string:filename>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>-<string:unique>/<int:width>x<int:height>',
    '/web/image/<int:id>-<string:unique>/<int:width>x<int:height>/<string:filename>'
]
```

so you could use one like the following:

```
'/web/image/hr.attendance.break/5/break_photo'
'/web/image/hr.attendance.break/5/resume_photo'
```

so in your controller you would generate such url for the response & the browser should load it, as following:

```py
@http.route('/api/hr.attendance.break', type='http', auth="none", methods=['GET'], csrf=False)
    def hr_attendance_breake_list(self, **payload):
        model = 'hr.attendance.break'
        ioc_name = model
        model = request.env[self._model].sudo().search(
            [('model', '=', model)], limit=1)

        custFields = [
            'id', 'employee_id', 'jam_istirahat', 'jam_lanjutKerja', 
            'x_long_break', 'y_lat_break', 'break_photo', 
            'x_long_resume', 'y_lat_resume', 'resume_photo'
            ]
        
        if model:
            domain, fields, offset, limit, order = extract_arguments(payload)
            fields = custFields
            data = request.env[model.model].sudo().search_read(
                domain=domain, fields=fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
            if data:
                for item in data:
                    item['break_photo'] = '/web/image/hr.attendance.break/{}/break_photo'.format(item['id'])
                    item['resume_photo'] = '/web/image/hr.attendance.break/{}/resume_photo'.format(item['id'])
                return valid_response(data)
            else:
                return valid_response(data)
        return invalid_response('invalid object model', 'The model %s is not availablee in the registry.' % ioc_name)
```

your final `json` should be as following:

```json
{
  "id": 65,
  "resume_photo": "/web/image/hr.attendance.break/65/resume_photo",
  "break_photo": "/web/image/hr.attendance.break/65/break_photo",
  "employee_id":[
      6,
      "Muhamed Irsan",
  ],
}
```

you could test this in your web browser, please note if the client is a mobile app or custom app, it has to fetch the image using the url. this should be done automatically. you have to deal with your custom client.